# Using results of SQL queries in other statements

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I can't seem to figure out to make join statements.

```
select usrs.*
from
    students s
    join system_users usrs on
        s.father=usrs.user_id
        OR s.mother=usrs.user_id
        OR s.guardian=usrs.user_id
where s.user_id = '201209083'
```

I have this query, and it returns :

```
+------------+---------+--------+--------+
| user_id    | contact | status | rights |
+------------+---------+--------+--------+
| f201209083 |    4093 | active | NULL   |
| g201209083 |    4095 | active | NULL   |
| m201209083 |    4094 | active | NULL   |
+------------+---------+--------+--------+
```

Now what I need is to use the information of the contact column to retrieve more information and join it with this table:

```
select
    *
from
    address
where
    contact_id = (contact column);
```

I need help with implementing it in one query.

P.S. Can someone tell me what this technique is called? I cannot find information on this by just searching for JOINs. Or a link to learn would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take that current statement as a sub-query and join it as such:

```
SELECT * FROM address 
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        usrs.* 
    FROM 
        students s 
        JOIN system_users usrs ON s.father=usrs.user_id OR s.mother=usrs.user_id OR s.guardian=usrs.user_id 
    WHERE 
        s.user_id = '201209083'
) AS temp 
ON contact_id = (contact column);
```

That should give you the original results combined with the results from the `address` table.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have several tables in a join, you can continue joining to more tables, like this:

```
Select a.*,usrs.*
from students s
join system_users usrs on s.father=usrs.user_id OR s.mother=usrs.user_id OR s.guardian=usrs.user_id
join addresses a on a.contact_id=usrs.contact
where s.user_id = '201209083'
```

Comment: Your answer only displays the result of the last query. I need both tables joined together.

Comment: @Cartman You can add `usrs.*` to the projection to get the results that you want.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to alter the first statement to return only the column you're evaluating against:

```
select usrs.contact
from
    students s
    join system_users usrs on
        s.father=usrs.user_id
        OR s.mother=usrs.user_id
        OR s.guardian=usrs.user_id
where s.user_id = '201209083'
```

...and then use that as the condition for evaluating contact_id:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    address
WHERE
    contact_id IN (
        SELECT usrs.contact
        FROM
            students s
            JOIN system_users usrs ON
                s.father=usrs.user_id
                OR s.mother=usrs.user_id
                OR s.guardian=usrs.user_id
        WHERE s.user_id = '201209083'
    )
```

This is often called a subquery or subselect, and it's [supported in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html) since 4.1. The ["IN" predicate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) will be true if contact_id matches any of the values returned by the inner query.

Comment: I think I need to sharpen my knowledge with 'IN'. Thanks :D

Comment: Glad to help. You might experiment with something simpler, like `SELECT * FROM address WHERE contact_id IN (4093, 4094, 4095)` to get a feel for what's happening. The subquery just generates the list dynamically.